# Rabbi Shlomo Zalman said Baruch Shepetarani with Shem UMalchut?

Tags: blessing, rabbis, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

I heard a story about Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auebuch that he said "Baruch Shepetarani" for his son with Shem UMalchut. Does anyone have a source for this story?

Usually we only say Baruch ShePetarni without Hashem's name because we don't know if we did a good job raising the child.

Comment: can you elaborate on the question, explaining why this is out of the ordinary

Comment: Can you source "usually..."?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the book Halichot Shelomo on Tefilla chapter 23 paragraph 40 where it quotes this story.