# Why don't we count sefirah without shem u'malkhut

Tags: halacha, blessing, sefirat-ha-omer, machlokes

Our current practice is that if you forget to count one day of the omer (morning and night), it is still incumbent upon you to count, but you can't say a bracha.

As far as I understand, the reason for this is that there is a makhlokhet about what the mitzvah is.  One opinion holds that counting each day is a mitzvah (so there are 49 mitzvot in the sefirah), while the other opinion holds that there is one mitzvah to count the whole sefirah.

Then Rav Soleveitchik comes along and says that the reason for not making a bracha on the omer if you forget a day is that counting, per se, must be sequential.  Otherwise, you're just saying a number.  I like this answer a lot.

But before Soleveitchik, how did we justify not making a bracha without *shem u'malkhut* (*"atah hashem elokeinu melekh ha'olam"*) as we do for most disputed mitzvot?

Comment: can you give examples of a bracha on a mitzvah said withou shem umalchus, in a case of safek?

Comment: @joshwaxman I know of only 5 such instances in Shulchan Aruch: birkot hashachar if you didn't do that action, hagomel, miracle location, chalitza, and shepterani. (OC 46:8 218:9 219:3 225:2 EH Chalitza 57). Also check out R A Lichtenstein's article on hagomel, part [I](http://etzion.org.il/en/birkat-ha-gomel-0) [II](http://etzion.org.il/en/birkat-ha-gomel-ii)

Comment: Charles, I think R' Josh is correct. Saying brachot without shem umalchut for all instances of safek is a relatively recent phenomenon. Without shem umalchut is not a bracha, so there isn't much point in saying it.

Comment: @joshwaxman There's also discussion somewhere early about redoing kiddushin at the chuppah (in a case where kiddushin originally happened earlier) for show and saying a bracha without shem umalchut. Also a teshuva of R Avraham b Harambam who tells the people of yemen (who don't have any grains) to make kiddush and bentch without shem umalchut on sorghum so that people don't forget how. it's a cool teshuva. These two aren't because of doubt though

Comment: What about those who have a custom to say "Boruch Shepetrani" at their son's bar mitzvah without Shem HaMalchut?" I dont have time to look it up now, but my understanding is that some say it without G-d's name because there is a doubt whether they discharged there obligation completely.

Comment: @Menachem see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12963/rabbi-shlomo-zalman-said-baruch-shepetarani-with-shem-umalchut

Comment: @Menachem I listed that bracha above. That reasoning is not the one brought by the Rama so it's probably a later reasoning.

Comment: Actually there are quite a few ברוך המקדש שמו ברבים (according to some people's Minhag), ברוך ק-ל ההודאות (in Modim Derabanan), ברוך חי העולמים (in Bore Nefoshos), ברוך שומע תפילה (at the end of Hininee on Rosh Hashana & YK).

Comment: @MeirZirkind None of those would have had malchut. The first three are all based on Yerushalmis and reflect a doubt if there should be a chatima, not if there should be a bracha. (Incidentally, there used to be a strong minhag Ashkenaz to say the middle two with shem. Don't see it too often nowadays though.) The last I assume is just nussach; do you have some reason to think a doubt is involved?

Comment: Here we go: see 5 http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur96.html#5, see end http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/432/5.htm, see end of 17 http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/51.htm, see 13&17 http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/52/11.htm, see 6&8 http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/52/12.htm, see 2&17 http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/52/13.htm

Comment: @MeirZirkind What's your point?

Comment: You Davka needed Shem Umalchus and Birkas Hamitzvos so I gave you a sampling.

Comment: @MeirZirkind I wanted old examples. I already agreed that such is done, just that it's a pretty recent phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

We are saying that since according to one opinion you are still obligated to say the Beracha properly it follows that you should hear the Beracha from the Chazzan (or someone else) so that it will be a fully valid Beracha (שומע כעונה) without even a doubt of a ברכה לבטלה.

To say the Beracha without Shem Umalchus is not an option if you could hear it from someone else (and perhaps one should go out of his way to do this correctly).

Comment: But shouldn't you still be told to say it without Shem Umalchus if you happen to be by yourself for whatever reason and can't hear the bracha from another?

Comment: No, because many people would get the wrong impression that it's a valid Beracha.

Comment: That's a novel explanation. Where else are we afraid someone might confuse an unreal bracha for a real one?

Comment: When forgetting Yaale Veyovo in Bentching on Rosh Chodesh we don't say it by Horachamon as we do if we forget Al Hanissim.

Comment: That's a machloket achronim I thought, but the Rama's concern there is shem shamayim levatalla IIRC not that it will be confused with a real bracha.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, the Rama says that but that can't be the only reason because we could say (like in Mi'ein Sholosh) "Vezochreinu Letovah Beyom Rosh Hachodesh Hazeh" which has no Shem. (To be honest the Kaf Hachayim says to say something similar but it's definitely, to my knowledge, not the done thing.)  I agree that there would be nothing wrong with saying the Beracha without Shem Umalchus, the question is only why it's not brought in SA to say it.

Comment: How do you know not to say "Vezochreinu..." after Mein Shalosh? The Rama didn't exclude that. So what support do you have for this idea of being afraid of people thinking it's a real bracha?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think you misunderstood me I was using Me'ein Sholsoh's sentence, I wasn't saying to or not to say anything in Me'ein Sholosh itself.