# Father liable for his own hitting?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring, chinuch-education

So a father “gets all the sins” of his son until the son becomes a bar mitzvah, where he is then responsible for his own sins. But if a son below bar mitzvah hits his father, violating a לא תעשה, does it make sense that the father should be punished (however that may work) for himself being hit?!

Comment: Why should it be any different?

Comment: @RabbiKaii the concept just seems weird, that you can be liable for something that happened to you

Comment: Who raised the child who hit his father?

Comment: @יהושעק Is the child's behavior always in the father's full control? Sometimes it's more nature than nurture, and the best efforts and education from the father won't make a difference in how the child acts. Should the father still be responsible for that?

Comment: @user9806 The father isn't culpable for being hit. He's culpable for his negligence in inadequately rearing his son which resulted in his son being someone who would do such a thing ([*Divrei Chamudos*, *B'rachos* 811](https://www.sefaria.org/Divrey_Chamudot_on_Berakhot.811?lang=bi), "אבל הכונה בברכה זו היא שמברך על שעד עתה היה חובה ומוטל על האב לחנכו במצות ולגדלו בתורה ונמצא כשמתרשל מכל זה שהוא נענש עליו ומעכשיו שנעשה בעצמו בר מצוה החובה על הבן עצמו ונמצא שהוא פטור מהעונש על ידו עוד"). It seems that if the son misbehaves despite the father's best efforts, the father isn't held responsible.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/122102/ (R' Shlomo Zalman's statement cited in the answer there might conflict with the Divrei Chamudos cited in the above comment).

Comment: @Fred There are people who are, for example, simply predisposed to violence by nature (i.e. genetically, developmentally, neurologically), even from a very young age. Holding the father (or anyone else really) responsible for failing to alter the behavior of such a child would not really make any sense.